# Upload and display images on IPFS via nft.storage using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, ipfs

I'm trying to read an image file and upload to IPFS using nft.storage API.

The code below works by converting the image to base64 string, but the nft.storage link only displays the string, not as an image as shown here -> https://bafkreihxiweiopz4pfmqtub5klhsq7wuu7wrw24inbrozbl7cshd4uaqxq.ipfs.dweb.link/

IF I decode the string, I could see the image. How to let IPFS display the image at the link?

```
<?php
    // image to string conversion
    $imagelink = file_get_contents($image_original_path); 
  
    // image string data into base64 
    $encdata = base64_encode($imagelink);

?>

<script>
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {
    
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://api.nft.storage/upload',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsIn...")
            },
            mimeType: 'multipart/form-data', // this too
            contentType: "image/png",
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            data: "<?php echo $encdata; ?>",
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              process the JSON data etc
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
           } 
        });
});
</script>
```